# Quais as desvantagens de proteger uma cadeia de objetos de um nullPointerException usando o map do optional?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, nullpointerexception, java-8

Por exemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
    Estado estado = new Estado(cidade);
    Endereco endereco = new Endereco(estado);
    Loja loja = new Loja(endereco);

    String nomeCidade;

    //null-safe ifs
    if(loja != null) {
        Endereco endereco1 = loja.getEndereco();

        if(endereco1 != null) {
            Estado estado1 = endereco1.getEstado();

            if(estado1 != null) {
                Cidade cidade1 = estado1.getCidade();

                if(cidade1 != null) {
                   nomeCidade = cidade1.getNome();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //null-safe optional

    Optional<Loja> lojaOptional = Optional.of(loja);

    nomeCidade = lojaOptional.map(Loja::getEndereco).map(Endereco::getEstado).map(Estado::getCidade).map(Cidade::getNome).orElse("SEM CIDADE CADASTRADA");
}
```

O objetivo é validar essa cadeia de objetos sem precisar de uma cadeia de ifs.

Comment: HelloWorld, foi intencional mesmo desmarcar a resposta do Maniero como a aceita, em favorecimento da minha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O que eu escrevo aqui primeiro vem de experiência que eu tenho na empresa e, depois, de absorver o que está escrita no artigo (em inglês) [Usar `Optional` corretamente não é opcional](https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional), publicado na DZone.

Como o Maniero mesmo falou, uma desvantagem objetiva do uso do `Optional` para esse fim é que a performance é pior. A HotSpot tenta amortecer isso fazendo otimizações no uso do `invokeDynamics`, mas são só amortizações que não chegarão ao nível da versão "puramente imperativa". Ele demonstra uma razão subjetiva quanto a isso que devo concordar: a pessoa/o time precisa estar acostumada/acostumado a esse idioma.

Existem outras desvantagens objetivas no uso do `Optional` além da performance. A principal que eu vejo: não é fácil tratar a nulidade intermediária.

Enquanto que num mundo de `if`s e `else`s é fácil determinar explicitamente onde ocorre cada mapeamento e como se comportar em casos de nulos, é uma tarefa árdua para se fazer com `Optional`.

Imagine que você deseja, por algum motivo, determinar quem foi o elemento nulo na cadeia. Com o jeito clássico de se programar ficaria algo assim:

```java
    int saltosNulidade = -1; // -1 significa que não houve nulos
    if (loja != null) {
        Endereco endereco1 = loja.getEndereco();
        if (endereco1 != null) {
            Estado estado1 = endereco1.getEstado();
            if (estado1 != null) {
                Cidade cidade1 = estado1.getCidade();
                if (cidade1 != null) {
                   nomeCidade = cidade1.getNome();
                } else {
                  saltosNulidade = 3; // conseguiu dar 3 saltos, mas parou num nulo
                }
            } else {
              saltosNulidade = 2; // conseguiu dar 2 saltos, mas parou num nulo
            }
        } else {
          saltosNulidade = 1; // conseguiu dar 1 salto, mas parou num nulo
        }
    } else {
      saltosNulidade = 0; // deu nulo já no primeiro passo
    }
```

Infelizmente, não há maneira trivial de se tratar de maneiras distintas o caso contrário no `Optional`. Você consegue até tratar o caso de "saltos positivos", a lógica complementar ao quantos saltos se deu até a nulidade. Mas, mesmo assim, desperdiça o uso dos lambdas:

```java
// só para permitir um closure com mudanças, já que o objeto no closure precisa ser
// efetivamente final, mas não seus campos
class IntIndirection {
  int x;
  IntIntidrection(int valorInicial) {
    x = valorInicial;
  }
}

// ...

//
<T, M> Operator<Function<T, M>> retornaMapIncremento(Function<T, M> mapeamento, IntIndirection saltos) {
  return orig -> {
    saltos.x += 1;
    return mapeamento.apply(orig);
  };
};

// ...

// para o caso de loja poder ser nulo também, usar o Optional.ofNullable
// .map(Estado::getCidade).map(Cidade::getNome).orElse("SEM CIDADE CADASTRADA")
Optional<Loja> lojaOptional = Optional.ofNullable(loja);

IntIndirection saltosNulidade = new IntIndirection(0);
lojaOptional.map(retornaMapIncremento(Loja::getEndereco, saltosNulidade))
  .map(retornaMapIncremento(Endereco::getEstado, saltosNulidade))
  .map(retornaMapIncremento(Estado::getCidade, saltosNulidade))
  .map(retornaMapIncremento(Cidade::getNome, saltosNulidade))
  .orElse("SEM CIDADE CADASTRADA");
```

Notou o esforço necessário para algo simples? E, como é o algoritmo de complemento, não é estritamente equivalente aquele apresentado anteriormente. O equivalente deste daqui seria o seguinte em versão imperativa:

```java
int saltosNulidade = 0;
if (loja != null) {
  saltosNulidade++;
  Endereco endereco1 = loja.getEndereco();
  if (endereco1 != null) {
    saltosNulidade++;
    Estado estado1 = endereco1.getEstado();
    if (estado1 != null) {
      saltosNulidade++;
      Cidade cidade1 = estado1.getCidade();
      if(cidade1 != null) {
         saltosNulidade++;
         nomeCidade = cidade1.getNome();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Entretanto, devo afirmar que a maior parte do "processamento em cadeia" que eu preciso fazer em códigos em produção não envolvem `else`s intermediários. Logo, apesar de essa ser uma desvantagem extrema no caso de uso que praticamente força o uso do tradicional `if-else`, ela não é extremamente comum.

Uma vantagem de se usar o mapeamento através do `Optional` é ficar *one-line*, com o caso de exceção explícito. Foi o que o Maniero pincelou em "tem a vantagem de ser mais curto assim", mas a melhoria estética aqui é um tanto além do "ficas mais curto". Fica mais direto também (claro, isso é algo subjetivo). Por exemplo, tirando este trecho de um código de produção:

```java
lbRiscoValue.setText(Optional.of(cliente)
  .map(Cliente::getRisco)
  .map(Risco::getDsRisco)
  .orElse("Sem resultado"));
```

Nessa modelagem, o objeto `cliente` pode não ter o campo `risco`, já `risco` é garantido ter um `dsRisco`. Também é garantido a existência do `cliente` neste trecho do código.

O equivalente imperativo do acima, dadas essas restrições acima, é:

```java
String textoLabel = "Sem resultado";
Risco r = cliente.getRisco();
if (r != null) {
  textoLabel = r.getDsRisco();
}

lbRiscoValue.setText(textoLabel);
```

ou então, alternativamente

```java
String textoLabel = null;
Risco r = cliente.getRisco();
if (r != null) {
  textoLabel = r.getDsRisco();
}

lbRiscoValue.setText(textoLabel != null? textoLabel: "Sem resultado");
```

ou então, alternativamente

```java
String textoLabel;
Risco r = cliente.getRisco();
if (r != null) {
  textoLabel = r.getDsRisco();
} else {
  textoLabel = "Sem resultado";
}

lbRiscoValue.setText(textoLabel);
```

Mais eficiente que a versão com `Optional`? Sim, com certeza. Mas a linha de código que reflete a ação desejada (`lbRiscoValue.setText`) é colocada como um detalhe com menos ênfase, enquanto que na versão com `Optional` isso fica mais evidente.

Antes de ter acesso ao `Optional` do Java 8, o projeto em que eu estava trabalhando usava Java 7, mas conseguimos usar lambda usando o Retrolambda. Para a maioria dos casos, não era necessário usar algo semelhante ao `Optional`, mas um mapeamento de um único nível (como o visto acima). Por isso, na época, criamos o [`Toolbox.getIfNotNull`](https://gitlab.com/geosales-open-source/totalcross-functional-toolbox/-/blob/83af3f4cb23cd03385dad2fdf0258deae48c6c4d/functional-toolbox/src/main/java/br/com/softsite/toolbox/Toolbox.java#L23-29). A versão com essa função seria a seguinte:

```java
lbRiscoValue.setText(Toolbox.getIfNotNull(cliente.getRisco(), Risco::getDsRisco, "Sem Resultado"));
```

Mais um exemplo um pouco menos trivial. Eu tenho um objeto do tipo `Verba`, que não pode ser instanciado. Mas ela conhece quais os tipos que ela pode ser e, dependendo de seu tipo, ela pode sofrer uma conversão implícita através de seus próprios métodos. Por exemplo, `Verba.asVerbaFinanceira()`, retorna um `Optional<VerbaFinanceira>` preenchido se, por acaso, a `Verba` for realmente uma `VerbaFinanceira`. Se não for o caso, retorna um `Optional.empty()`. Pode acontecer de uma `VerbaFinanceira` causar um tipo de pendência específico. É assim que ficou o código:

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(verba).flatMap(Verba::asVerbaFinanceira)
    .map(VerbaFinanceira::getTipoBlocPedidoSit)
    .map(TipoBlocPedidoSit::getCdTipoBloc)
    .map(TipoPedidoPendente::getTipoPedidoPendenteFromMnemonico)
    .orElse(null);
```

O equivalente interativa disso seria (vamos imaginar que exista o método `isVerbaFinanceira()` que retorna `false` quando o `asVerbaFinanceira()` retorna um `Optional.empty()` e `true` para o caso contrário):

```java
TipoPedidoPendente tpp = null;
if (verba != null) {
  if (verba.isVerbaFinanceira()) {
    VerbaFinanceira vf = (VerbaFinanceira) verba;
    TipoBlocPedidoSit tbps = vf.getTipoBlocPedidoSit();
    if (tbps != null) {
      Integer cdTipoBloc = tbps.getCdTipoBloc();
      if (cdTipoBloc != null) {
        tpp = TipoPedidoPendente.getTipoPedidoPendenteFromMnemonico(cdTipoBloc);
      }
    }
  }
}
return tpp;
```

Note que o valor `default` (no caso `null`) é inicializado em `tpp` logo no começo. Se  tivesse outro valor para indicar esse padrão, iniciar `tpp` com esse outro valor seria um erro. Por sinal, exatamente por conta desse erro que eu não coloquei o `return` dentro do nível mais aninhado dos `if`s. Se existisse outro valor a ser retornado (suponha que seja a constante `TipoPedidoPendente.ALGO`), os códigos seriam os seguintes:

```java
return Optional.ofNullable(verba).flatMap(Verba::asVerbaFinanceira)
    .map(VerbaFinanceira::getTipoBlocPedidoSit)
    .map(TipoBlocPedidoSit::getCdTipoBloc)
    .map(TipoPedidoPendente::getTipoPedidoPendenteFromMnemonico)
    .orElse(TipoPedidoPendente.ALGO);
```

```java
TipoPedidoPendente tpp = null;
if (verba != null) {
  if (verba.isVerbaFinanceira()) {
    VerbaFinanceira vf = (VerbaFinanceira) verba;
    TipoBlocPedidoSit tbps = vf.getTipoBlocPedidoSit();
    if (tbps != null) {
      Integer cdTipoBloc = tbps.getCdTipoBloc();
      if (cdTipoBloc != null) {
        tpp = TipoPedidoPendente.getTipoPedidoPendenteFromMnemonico(cdTipoBloc);
      }
    }
  }
}
return tpp != null? tpp: TipoPedidoPendente.ALGO;
```

Existem outros usos para o `Optional` além do "proteger contra NPE", que é o citado na pergunta. Só irei pincelar um pouco sobre um desses outros usos, sem entrar em muitos detalhes: processamento em uma função de um valor não nulo.

Por exemplo, eu preciso que seja preenchido, em um componente visual, quais são os elementos selecionados de uma lista. Por acaso, essa tela, na modelagem em que ela foi criada, recebe como argumento o objeto a ser modificado (se for uma atualização do objeto) ou nulo (novo objeto). O objeto em questão é o `usuarioAlcadaAprovacaoDTO`.

> Por questões de otimizações no GWT, tempo de startup e dificuldade em separar em menores módulos GWT do projeto, muito do preenchimento dos objetos na tela se faz através do que chamamos informalmente de `Tripleta`, que consiste de um código, um texto e um classificador, esse classificador usado para diminuir quantidade de chamadas ajax via GWT-RPC, permitindo uma multiplexação dos resultados

Para mapear desse objeto até quem deve ser preenchido, faço o seguinte:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(this.usuarioAlcadaAprovacaoDTO)
  .map(UsuarioAlcadaAprovacaoDTO::getUsuarios)
  .map(usuarios -> usuarios.stream().map(p -> new Tripleta(p, Constantes.USUARIO_SISTEMA)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
  .ifPresent(usuariosSelect::setSelectedValues);
```

Note que eu só preencho o valor em `usuariosSelect` se o objeto for de atualização, se ele tiver preenchido quais usuários devo preencher e ainda apenas após o mapeamento de `Usuario` para `Tripleta`. Supostamente, como `getUsuarios` retorna uma coleção, deveria ser garantido que essa coleção não é nula, no máximo vazia. De toda sorte, fica claro a quem está acostumado com esse idioma que o foco é chamar `usuariosSelect.setSelectedValues(usuarios)`, todo o resto anterior é apenas o modo para fazer essa chamada.

O equivalente sem `Optional` (nem `Stream`, nesse caso) disso seria:

```java
if (this.usuarioAlcadaAprovacaoDTO != null) {
  List<Usuario> usuarios = this.usuarioAlcadaAprovacaoDTO.getUsuarios();

  // vou assumir que não é nulo por questões de razoabilidade
  ArrayList<Tripleta> usuariosAsTripletas = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Usuario usuario: usuarios) {
    usuariosAsTripletas.add(new Tripleta(usuario, Constantes.USUARIO_SISTEMA));
  }
  usuariosSelect.setSelectedValues(usuariosAsTripletas);
}
```

Para quem está acostumado com esse idioma, fica claro que o foco é chamar `usuariosSelect.setSelectedValues`.

Uma outra vantagem é o `else` do `ifPresentOrElse` (Java 9, que o GWT não suportava mas que eu fiz um amplo *backport*). Nele, você faz todos os mapeamentos necessários e, então, toma uma de duas ações disponíveis:

- se houver valor mapeado no final
- na ausência de valor no final

Peguemos o caso:

```java
lbRiscoValue.setText(Optional.of(cliente)
  .map(Cliente::getRisco)
  .map(Risco::getDsRisco)
  .orElse("Sem resultado"));
```

Para tratar a ausência de valor no final, poderia fazer o seguinte:

```java
Optional.of(cliente)
  .map(Cliente::getRisco)
  .map(Risco::getDsRisco)
  .ifPresentOrElse(
      lbRiscoValue::setText,
      () -> showToast("Sem risco associado ao cliente")
  );
```

O equivalente imperativo seria algo assim:

```java
String text = null;
Risco r = cliente.getRisco();

if (r != null) {
  text = r.getDsRisco();
}

if (text != null) {
  lbRiscoValue.setText(text);
} else {
  showToast("Sem risco associado ao cliente");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A maior desvantagem que eu vejo é que não é muito legível.

Porém legibilidade tem a ver com com contexto. Se todo mundo fizer isso pode tornar-se normal.

Mas eu olho isso e não sei bem o que faz mesmo tendo quase 40 anos de experiência e conhecer bem o idioma funcional. Olhando com mais cuidado dá para entender, ou seja, não é legível. Parece abuso, e talvez por falta de ter um recurso mais simples na linguagem.

Outra desvantagem é a performance que é um pouco inferior, ainda que talvez não esteja precisando se preocupar com isso nesse caso.

Obviamente que tem a vantagem de ser mais curto assim.

Mas fico pensando se o correto é se o objeto que tem esses dados não deveria garantir que não fosse nulo. Nem sempre dá, mas em muitos casos não só dá como é o correto a ser feito.

A modelagem parece errada também.